# Question about adding an HVAC circuit

Tags: hvac, circuit

[image]

So am I reading this right? I can use a 30 amp breaker and fused disconnect and thus us a 10ga wire to build this circuit?

Answer (score 3):

You may run the risk of nuisance trips on compressor start, I suspect, but yes, that is the minimum they call for.

If wire cost is your issue, #6 (or #8 THWN in conduit if your breakers have 75C terminals as mine do) aluminum would save money but allow for a 40A breaker.